# Why does this program have a run-time error?

Tags: c, file, io, stack

```
#define String char*
#define FileP FILE*
#define null ((void*) 0)
#include "defs.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    Stack stack;
    init(&stack);

    FileP file = readp("Props.props");

    if (file == null){
        printf("Unable to Load\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    String buffer;
    int m = 0;
    char ch;

    while (!feof(file)) {
        ch = getc(file);
        if (ch != ' ') {
            *(buffer + (m++)) = ch;
        } else {
            push(&stack, buffer);
            m = 0;
        }
    }

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", pop(&stack));
    }

     fclose(file);

     return 0;

}
```

defs.h contains all the #defines, but I included them here so you know what they are. This program opens a text file called "props.props" and reads each string, then stores them into a stack and finally prints the stack out. Nothing happens during run-time, only that it quits due to a run-time error. Why is this happening?

Comment: Exactly which run-time error is it showing you?

Comment: It doesn't show me, it just says run-time error

Comment: Please provide with the definitions of functions like readp() and etc... its hard to track from this code.

Answer (score 1):

`buffer` is uninitialized. You need to allocate memory with

```
buffer = (char*) malloc(n * sizeof (char));
```

where n is the number of characters you need to store.
Also, the file does not seem to have been opened anywhere(`fopen`). What is `readp`?

Comment: readp has the fopen method in it, and thanks, i usually have bugs like this that are very obvious.